# pandoc to PDF not putting a shaded block around language specific code sections

Tags: pdf, texlive, pandoc

I have the following text in my .md file:

```
### Table of Contents, List of Tables, List of Figures

The example below shows how to place a table of contents, a list of
tables, and a list of figures, each in its own page.

~~~ latex
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
~~~
```

When this is processed with the below command:

```
pandoc --number-sections \
    --toc --variable lof=true --variable lot=true \
    --filter pantable \
    --filter pandoc-tablenos \
    --filter pandoc-fignos \
    --filter pandoc-latex-fontsize \
    --from markdown \
    --standalone \
    --template=template.latex
    --variable subparagraph:yes \
    --variable colorlinks:yes \
    --to latex \
    --output document.txt \
    document.md
```

The code block does not have a shaded block around it.  When I have the same sections, but without the `latex` after the first set of `~~~`, the shaded block is produced, but I loose the language formatting.  I looked at a bunch of potential solutions including adding the following to the template.latex file:

```
$if(highlighting-macros)&
$highlighting-macros&
$end$
```

I get the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \VerbBar already defined.
             Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

The code that is generated by pandoc for the above is:

```
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighing}
\FunctionTok{\textbackslash{}newpage}
\FunctionTok{\textbackslash{}tableofcontents}
\FunctionTok{\textbackslash{}newpage}
\FunctionTok{\textbackslash{}listoftables}
\FunctionTok{\textbackslash{}newpage}
\FunctionTok{\textbackslash{}listoffigures}
\FunctionTok{\textbackslash{}newpage}
\end{Highlighing}
\end{Shaded}
```

When not indicating the language, the same section would be generated as:

```
\begin{verbatim}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\end{verbatim}
```

The version of pandoc that I am using is:

```
pandoc 2.2.2
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.4.2, texmath 0.11, skylighting 0.7.0.2
```

using `Tex Live 2013/Debian`.

and is running on (I cannot upgrade at this time):

```
Linux myhostname 4.4.0-96-generic #119-14-04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 08:40:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I need to be able to use code blocks with language specifiers that generate shaded blocks around the code when generating a PDF file.

NOTE: I am not having an issue with generating an HTML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `$ pandoc --to latex test.md  --highlight-style tango  -o test.pdf`

[image: mwe]

To see the available styles: `pandoc --list-highlight-styles`

Comment: Thanks.  This did what I was looking to do.  In the end I exported the tango style to a file, updated it for my needs and use that file on the `--highlight-style` qualifier.  This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You can also customize the theme with `pandoc --print-highlight-style pygments > my.theme` and then use it with `pandoc --highlight-style my.theme`. The theme file is a JSON-like text file that is pretty straightforward to edit.

Comment: @mallwright Good point.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `--highlight-style=<xxxx>` to your Pandoc command. For possible values of `<xxxx>` make your pick from `pandoc --list-highlight-styles`.

I frequently use `--highlight-style=espresso`. (I slightly modified your Markdown to fit all output on one page, and to really show highlighting of LaTeX code for the screenshot below.) The result:

[image]