# R Markdown/pandoc: Change how code blocks are converted to LaTeX

Tags: r, pandoc, knitr, markdown

I use `rmarkdown` to generate a pdf file (which uses `pandoc`, which in turn uses `pdflatex`). By enabling `keep_tex` option, I noticed that code blocks without language type always become `verbatim`, e.g.:

````
```
my code block
```
````

becomes:

```
\begin{verbatim}
my code block
\end{verbatim}
```

Is it possible to change conversion rules (e.g. in case I want to change background color for those blocks)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. I don't have time to give a full answer, you can tell `knitr` to use `listings` (see https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/listings/) and you can tell get `tcolorbox` to put listings into boxes for you. See [How to use lstlisting with tcolorbox?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/483289) for an example.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for replying. I've tried to experiment, and it seems to me that `knitr` hooks only work for `R` code chunks, is that correct? I'm wondering if it's possible to apply this to chunks without language specification.

Comment: Yes, that may be true, I'm not sure. But `pandoc` can definitely use `listings` so it should still be possible in principle, if not directly through `knitr`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yep, specifying `pandoc_args: [ "--listings" ]` works. You can post that as an answer. Also, some good ideas on customization here: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2692

Comment: I think I mainly pointed you in the right direction, so it might be better to post your test example and explanation as in answer yourself. :)

Comment: What is exactly your goal?  a chunk starting with ```{r foo, echo=F,eval=F}   show the R code with syntax highlight and color background without listings and without tcolorbox, and that style can be changed.

Comment: @Fran You know more than me about this, so if there's an answer without either, it would be worth having. (Although I think that showing how to use the other packages for code display would also be worth having.)

Comment: @AlanMunn I suspect of a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) but if Thunderbeef clarify the problem I will glad to try to answer. Nonetheless,  maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466425/pandoc-to-pdf-not-putting-a-shaded-block-around-language-specific-code-sections) example,  or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505702/how-can-i-get-rchunks-to-render-inside-tcolorbox) example, are enough.

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks again, I've posted the answer that I came up with.

Comment: @Fran Sorry if question wasn't clear. I specifically wanted to modify how chunks defined between tripple backticks and without explicit languange definition look, without having to put every such chunk into `LaTeX` macro manually. Anyway, I found the solution already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @AlanMunn, I found at least 2 solutions that work for code chunks with undefined language. Both are `pandoc`-specific, and don't actually require `rmarkdown` (examples for both can be found [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2692)):

## 1. Call pandoc with --listings option

In `rmarkdown`, it can be passed like this:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: [ "--listings" ]
---
```

This will make it so all code blocks (including ones without defined language) will instead be wrapped in `lstlisting` like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
my code block
\end{lstlisting}
```

With this, you have the option to customize appearance of those blocks by doing the following:

1. Define your own language with `\lstdefinelanguage` to use in default style
2. Define default style with `\lstset` to change appearance of chunks with unspecified language

## 2. Use pandoc filter

In `rmarkdown`, it can be passed like this:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: [ "--filter", "./my-cool-filter" ]
---
```

"Filter" is an executable written in any language that can process JSON. `pandoc` will convert the entire document into JSON dictionary, and pipe it through the filter, then work with the result. So, a filter can modify output in any arbitrary way.

In this particular case, you basically need to find all elements with "CodeBlock" type, and convert them into "RawBlock" with "tex" subtype, and wrap text value into any `LaTeX` macro of your liking.

**UPD:** It's even easier (and, apparently, faster, according to [documentation](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html)), to use `--lua-filter` option. The whole code of the filter is just this:

```
function CodeBlock(elem)
  return pandoc.RawBlock('tex', '\\begin{my-cool-macro}\n' .. elem.text .. '\n\\end{my-cool-macro}')
end
```